# Not searching all folders in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

Is there any way to change how the CTRL-SHIFT-F search works. I want to force it to ignore searching through certain directories?

Answer (score 0):

Select a folder in the Files tab (ctrl+2), and press ctrl+f to search within the folder and sub-folders.